# Manually selecting audio output

Tags: sound, kubuntu, kde, pulseaudio, phonon

I just installed Kubuntu 15.04 and I am trying to configure audio output in a usable way.

Since I am using both a USB headset and speakers at my system I need to manually (*only* manually) switch the used audio output device. I found a nice tool that allows selecting the desired output from tray (http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/sound-switcher-ubuntu-indicator.html).

This works fine... until I load another music file e.g. in Amarok. The multimedia system immediately and automatically switches the audio output according to the ouput priorities configured for the phonon audio framework in the KDE settings panel.

So if speakers have highest priority I can not use the headset since the system repeatedly switches back to speakers. The other way around, if headset has highest priority I can not use the speakers since the system repeatedly switches back to headset.

Is there a solution for this nasty problem?

Anyway I do not need priority based audio output selection at all. Is there a way to disable it completely?

Comment: What do you think about this one here http://superuser.com/questions/919033/quickly-change-audio-device-in-kde

Comment: Well, not an easy solution. If there really is no better way, I will try that. What a shame, that such an easy problem can not be solved without programming :-(